# Record live streaming video with WebRTC and stream with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm trying to develop a website that basically lets a user visit a page, and lets say click a button, and use their built in camera to live stream videos with audio to others that visit another url.

I need some clarity on what I need to develop, what I can get from 3rd party to save time. AWS looks to cover all the encoding and delivery http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/, but I'm confused on the process on which I should record and delivery the content to S3. Just to much information overload.

In all my research I looks like I should build a WebRTC, which I have done, then transport that data with javascript from the clients browser to my server, and thus to AWS. Is this the best format, or should I been using a 3rd party thats putting more time into that element?

I have seen the Kurento project, as well as this [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) project.

Like I said, I'm finding there is just to much information overload on the topic.

So what are my options for:

- In browser recording with WebRTC. Anything else I should do or just force users to roll up to a supporting browser?
- WebRTC means I have to do Javascript for the delivery, is node a better option for the server to take delivery of this streaming data?
- Anything else I need to know before I pass it off to S3 for delivery to the cloud front?

As you can see the core of my question comes within the recording and transporting the data to the web server so I can delivery it for streaming.

Comment: Continuing to provide my findings for others:

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/PHP/

So far I have only found examples of how to record then upload when the video is complete vs streaming it to the server. I need a one way stream so I can push it into S3 and cloudfront for viewing by others in real time.

Comment: WebRTC is PeerToPeer, if you want to stream to many people, you should use an MCU like [Janus-Gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) or [Licode](https://github.com/ging/licode). This is so your browser can send the media to this MCU, and then people can make either their own WebRTC peerconnections with the server, or provide the strema through another means. Also, S3 charges can get steep when stream high quality media(charges by the GB), keep that in mind.

Comment: did you find any solution, i simply want to save video directly to s3 from client browser, it doesn't even have to  involve webrtc

Comment: Sorry I don't recall really, but I don't think we did. We end up abandoning the project due to how complex it was.

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for the same thing.
In 2020, it seems it should be possible with [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) and then uploading blobs / multiform data directly to S3.